# Fire disappears in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I've been trying to render a flame in blender 2.8. It appears fine in my viewport. However, the flame disappears when the rendering is complete and everything turns black. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Viewport:

[image: viewport view]

Rendered Image:

[image: black screen]

Here is my node setup for the smoke domain:

[image: node setup for fire in blender 2.8]

Comment: Hard to tell with the current information. Did you bake the simulation cache? Is the domain object enabled for rendering (camera icon)?. Is there another object blocking the view? Edit your question and add more information. Also, you don't need the additional emission node, the principled volume node, just plug the color ramp to the color socket for emission and the value to emission strength

Comment: @susu yes i did bake the simulation. could you please tell me where to find the setting which enables the domain object?